# Cygwin : Convert *.xlsb files into *.csv:

Tags: excel, unix, cygwin

Would like to know is there any command available to convert excel files (*.xlsb) into (*.csv) from a specific folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Informatica offers a free downloadable utility for UNIX that you could try: https://community.informatica.com/solutions/excel_to_csv_converter_unix